# Lazarus IDE: Importing images in the project

Tags: lazarus, delphi

I'm starting to develop projects in Lazarus IDE, and I'm not adapted to the new platform. How can I import audio media, images, videos and other resources in the project and so use them (without the need to use a specific directory of the operating system).

Taking advantage of the same situation, it would be feasible to create a zip file type and import it into the project or create a package containing these resources.

**NOTE:** I want to use the images in a `TImage` object and define the resources imported into the `picture` property.

Comment: [Lazarus Resources](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Resources)

Answer (score 1):

for images:

myImage.picture.LoadFromFile('img.bmp');
or
myImage.picture.LoadFromFile('folder1/img.bmp');  // not only .bmp is allowed
at the beggining you are in the same folder as the application is

about sounds:
the sound's format is required to be .wav
in youtube are some good tutorials
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkhV7FuUpI4

good luck